# Error GetData() when make adapter variable

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I was watch Android tutorial from Slidenerd about make Recycle View on  Android. This the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OoCySqneJno.

When i make a adapter variable, i got an error. This is my full code:

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**

```
package com.balinez.wdharmana.doahindu;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME="testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER="user_learned_drawer";
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private BalinezAdapter adapter;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private View containerView;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer=Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,"false"));

        if(savedInstanceState!=null) {
            mFromSavedInstanceState=true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
        adapter = new BalinezAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return layout;
    }

    public static List<Information> getData() {
        List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_bookmark1, R.drawable.ic_bookmark1};
        String[] titles={"Doa Sehari-Hari", "Doa Sembahyang"};

        for (int i=0; i<titles.length && i<icons.length; i++) {
            Information current = new Information();
            current.iconId = icons[i];
            current.title = titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }



    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if(!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer=true;
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        if(!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName,preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

I got an error in this code:

```
adapter = new BalinezAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
```

I also include my Adapter source code:

```
 package com.balinez.wdharmana.doahindu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by WDHARMANA on 27/07/2015.
 */
public class BalinezAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <BalinezAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private  LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Information> data= Collections.emptyList();

    public BalinezAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Information current=data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.title);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
            icon= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
        }
    }
}
```

This is **information.java** file:

```
package com.balinez.wdharmana.doahindu;

/**
 * Created by WDHARMANA on 27/07/2015.
 */
public class Information {
    int iconId;
    String title;
}
```

I have try solution on some Stackoverflow thread. But it doestn't work for me. If you have same problem, you can share it for us. Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your adapter constructor is

```
 public BalinezAdapter(Context context) {
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

While you have

```
new BalinezAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
```

You missed the second argument in the adapter.

Just change to

```
  List<Information> data;
 public BalinezAdapter(Context context,List<Information> mList) {
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    data = mList;  
}
```

and change this

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```